# Iterating through multiple URLs using Requests and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Can anyone weigh on in ways to iterate through multiple URLs, which I can define in advance, using Requests and Beautiful Soup? Attached is what I have so far, i.e. trying to put the URls in a list, but that's not working.

```
import requests
import bs4
URLs = ["https://example-url-1.com", "https://example-url-2.com"]
result = requests.get(URLs)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")

print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

I'm also looking for a way to include a interval delay so as not to SPAM the server.

Comment: if I am not wrong I can divide your problem into basically 2 subparts. The first is to iterate all the URLs. The second is to have a delay in between every request

Comment: ...and when someone says "iterate", you should think "loop". Loop over the list of URLs, and within the loop, fetch a single url, then process it with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: It's called a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score 1):

Heres a little verbose solution

```
import requests
import bs4
import sleep from time
URLs = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=6',
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=5',
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=4'
        ]

def getPage(url):
    print('Indexing {0}......'.format(url))
    result = requests.get(url)
    print('Url Indexed...Now pausing 50secs before next ')
    sleep(50)
    return result

results = map(getPage, URLs)
for result in results:
    # soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")
    print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

Comment: You've to use `requests.Session()` if you care about not getting blocked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments about the for loop. I was able to answer this myself! Here's the code I used:

```
from time import sleep
import requests
import bs4

URLs = ["https://example-url-1.com", "https://example-url-2.com"]

for x in URLs:
    print(x)
    result = requests.get(x)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.find_all('p'))
    sleep(50)
```